# Sphinx4: recognize() won't run the second time

Tags: java, speech-recognition, keyword, sphinx4

i am using sphinx4 to pause a thread until a specific keyword is spoken. This works great the first time, but the second time i need to pause the thread, the

```
recognizer.recognize()
```

seems to not run and the application just starts spamming "Start speaking...".

Here is the function to pause the thread:

```
public synchronized void waitForKeyword(String in){


    if (!microphone.startRecording()) {
        System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
        recognizer.deallocate();
        System.exit(1);
    }


    Result result = null;

    while(true) {

        if(microphone.isRecording()) {
            System.out.println("Start speaking...\n");  
            result = recognizer.recognize();
        }else{
            microphone.startRecording();
        }

        if (result != null) {
            String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
            System.out.println("You said: " + resultText + '\n');

            if(resultText.equals(in)){                      
                microphone.stopRecording();
                speak("At your service!");
                break;
            }

        }

    }


}
```

What am i doing wrong, and how do i fix this problem?

Cheers!

Comment: Provide information about OS and JDK. Make sure you are using Oracle JDK, others do not work with microphone properly.

Comment: Windows 7 home premium 64bit. Orcale JDK1.7.0_17.

Answer (score 2):

You must call `microphone.clear()` after the first use. Works for me with OpenJDK. I am working on a demo application that demonstrates this use case, it should be included in the next release of Sphinx4 so stay tuned.